# How can I get the ActionBar to render?

Tags: android, xml, rendering

I'm a new to Android development and I've been giving Android Studio a spin. I've followed [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html) and I still haven't been able to get the ActionBar up and running either on the emulator or on the real device. I've specified the min version in the manifest file and I've also edited the menu and activity xml files accordingly.

Confusingly, the UIs shown in the activity_foo.xml and menu_foo.xml are different:

activity_foo.xml:
[image]

menu_foo.xml:
[image]

Even more confusingly, the final app when built shows both the Search and Settings in the hamburger menu though I do not recall seeing it in the GUI previews:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Confusingly, the UIs shown in the activity_foo.xml and menu_foo.xml are different

They are supposed to be different. One is showing you a layout file. The other is showing you a menu resource. Their previews are not supposed to necessarily match. After all, an Android app that is bigger than a breadbox will have many layout resources, few of which will be defining the contents of an activity.

For those layouts that *do* define the contents of an activity, IIRC, you can have the same `tools:context=".FooActivity"` in the root element of your layout file, and the preview may take that into account.

> Even more confusingly, the final app when built shows both the Search and Settings in the hamburger menu though I do not recall seeing it in the GUI previews:

In the preview, the search item is represented by a toolbar-style button (icon is a magnifying glass).

In your menu resource, you have one `<item>` that has `android:showAsAction` and one `<item>` that has `app:showAsAction`. Either you are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport, or you are not. That would be determined by things like:

- what Java class your activity inherits from (`ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` for `appcompat-v7`)
- what theme you are using for the activity in your manifest (if it is based on `Theme.AppCompat.*`, you are using `appcompat-v7`)

If you are using `appcompat-v7`, you need to change the `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction`. Given the results of your run of the project in the emulator, my guess is that you are using `appcompat-v7`. If you make the change to the menu resource and run the project again, you may see the search item show up as the magnifying glass icon, as you see in the preview. I say "may" because there may or may not be room to show that toolbar-style icon, depending on screen size and orientation of the device that runs your app — action bar items with `ifRoom` will show as toolbar-style buttons if there is room or will fall into the overflow menu if not.

Comment: Thanks, all it needed was a app:showAsAction="always"